# Se detiene la página al utilizar @input vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un componente llamado B-DATEPICKER que me brinda [BUEFY](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/datepicker) para mostrar un campo de fechas:

El problema que tengo es cuando llamo a la función desde aquí para que cuando cambie la fecha llame a la función **DetailTracking()** pero se congela la página web y no responde.

```
<b-datepicker
   v-model="dateFilter"
   @input="detailTracking()"
   icon="calendar" expanded>
</b-datepicker>
```

A que se debe este problema?
Ojo: la función funciona correctamente porque cuando lo llamo desde un setInterval si hace la llamada a dicha función:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.detailTracking();
}, 30000);
```

Hay otra forma de llamar a la función al cambiar la fecha?

**UPDATE**

```
detailTracking(track) {
        this.isEmpty = false;
        this.isLoadingContainer = true;
        this.cont += 1;
        if(this.cont <= 1){
          this.dateFilter = track.date;
          this.licenseName = track.license;
        }
        this.dateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateFilter))
        this.nPositions = 0;
        const data = {
          param: this.licenseName,
          date: moment(this.dateFilter).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        };
        this.axios.post('tracking/filter-vehicle/', data)
          .then((response) => {
            this.isDetail = true;
            this.tracking = response.data.results;
            if(this.tracking.length !== 0) {
              this.tracking.forEach((t) => {
                t.position = { lat: t.latitude, lng: t.longitude };
                this.nPositions += 1;
              });
              this.pointsGps = this.tracking.map((d) => {
                const p = {
                  lat: parseFloat(d.latitude, 10),
                  lng: parseFloat(d.longitude, 10),
                };
                return p;
              });
              this.center = this.tracking[0].position;
              this.isLoadingContainer = false;
            }
            else {
              this.isEmpty = true;
              this.copytracking.forEach((l)=>{
                if(l.license === this.licenseName){
                  this.tracking = [l];
                }
              });
              this.tracking.forEach((t) => {
                t.position = { lat: t.latitude, lng: t.longitude };
                this.nPositions += 1;
              });
              this.pointsGps = this.tracking.map((d) => {
                const p = {
                  lat: parseFloat(d.latitude, 10),
                  lng: parseFloat(d.longitude, 10),
                };
                return p;
              });
              this.center = this.tracking[0].position;
              this.isLoadingContainer = false;
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que hace la función `detailTracking`?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta amigo @GermanAlzate tambien he probado con watch pero me dice que se genera un bucle infinito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era el siguiente:

```
this.dateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateFilter));
```

este hacia un cambio al v-model this.datafilter cada vez que se ejecutaba la función y como hacia un cambio de nuevo llamaba al @input y así infinitamente
Entonces para que solo se ejecute una vez lo puse arriba donde solo quiero que se ejecute una vez:

```
if(this.cont <= 1){
   this.dateFilter = track.date;
   this.licenseName = track.license;
   this.dateFilter = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateFilter));
}
```

De esta manera esta funcionando correctamente :D